# How add a running Id new column to Spark Data frame ( pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have the following dataframe :

```html
timestamp       sum
31/01/2017 09:00 0
31/01/2017 10:00 0
31/01/2017 11:00 0
31/01/2017 12:00 2
31/01/2017 13:00 2
31/01/2017 14:00 2
31/01/2017 15:00 11
```

And would like add a new Id column - just a running number like that :

```html
+----------------+---+---------+
|       timestamp|sum|running_id|
+----------------+---+---------+
|2017-01-31 09:00|  0|        0|
|2017-01-31 10:00|  0|        1|
|2017-01-31 11:00|  0|        2|
|2017-01-31 12:00|  2|        3|
|2017-01-31 13:00|  2|        4|
|2017-01-31 14:00|  2|        5|
|2017-01-31 15:00| 11|        6|
```

I did it like this :

```css
sub_data_spark =  sub_data_spark.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[0][0],x[0][1],x[1])).toDF(sub_data_spark.columns+["running_id"])
```

Some one can advice for a "cleaner" way ?

Thanks,
Boris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `select *, row_Number() over ( order by sum) from table`

or any column based on logic. Can also use PARTITION BY clause.

Comment: If no PartitionBy clause is added this would basically shuffle all the data to a single partition which wouldn't be good for parallelism.

Comment: Thanks, this one works . How can I use the PartitionBy  and keep the timestamp ordered ( the order of rows should remain the same )

Comment: select *, row_Number() over ( Partition by TO_DATE(timestamp) order by sum) from table .  This will send all the data of different date to different partition. But for all partition counting will start from 1 again. This methord have its own pros and cons. Use it based on your usecase.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to that without zipWithIndex or zipWithUniqueId you should use the function [monotonically_increasing_id](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id)

This function works like this:

> A column that generates monotonically increasing 64-bit integers.
>
> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and
>   unique, but not consecutive. The current implementation puts the
>   partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each
>   partition in the lower 33 bits. The assumption is that the data frame
>   has less than 1 billion partitions, and each partition has less than 8
>   billion records.

So for your case you can use like this:

```
sub_data_spark.withColumn('Id', monotonically_increasing_id()).show()
```

This will return to you the Unique ID for your model. But it will not start in 0 and will not be sequential

Comment: Thanks,  I do look for a monotonically increasing and unique numbers => row numbers

Comment: It does work but how about the scenario when you want 32 bit integers and not 64 bit? Truncation here would cause problems.

Comment: According to Spark code you are going to use 64bits its a long: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/MonotonicallyIncreasingID.scala#L48